# Unable to crop image using mini_magick

Tags: minimagick

I am using mini_magick as the interface of utilizing ImageMagick to manipulate some image. **The resize works fine**. But when I want to crop some image:

```
img = MiniMagick::Image.open(url)
img.crop('200x800!')
```

It constantly prompts `No such file`

```
No such file or directory - /var/folders/c4/mqlwdx_d3kj6hqcnvbjr9mn80000gn/T/mini_magick20120504-11111-16kayc1.png
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ah, I was searching with wrong key phrase I guess. The right answer come to me when I search `minimagick` instead of `mini_magick`. [Undefined Method crop! Using Carrierwave with MiniMagick on rails 3.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418973/undefined-method-crop-using-carrierwave-with-minimagick-on-rails-3-1-3) especially this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9961434/179691

I did know the stuff about mini_magick is just a wrapping of `mogrify` and so. The cause of my problem is that `-crop` accepts full formatted geometry only. so I changed the expression to:

```
img.crop('200x800+0+0')
```

and that works.

Comment: Works for jekyll-minimagick and retinamagick too! ```crop: "640x480+0+0"```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if anyone is using Carrierwave to crop and upload image directly to Amazon S3, the correct way to do for me is the following:

image_uploader.rb

```
url=model.remote_image_url 
crop_params="#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}"
manipulate! do |img|
  img = MiniMagick::Image.open(url)
  img.crop(crop_params)
  img = yield(img) if block_given?
  img
end
```

The reason I'm adding img = MiniMagick::Image.open(url) is because if I don't specify my own image, it would throw me the following error:

```
mogrify.im6: geometry does not contain image `/tmp/mini_magick20150811-15523-ac8go1.jpeg'
```

I think it's some default temporary path that mini_magick would try to find the image, but since the image is held remotely in S3, it couldn't find it.