# Carrierwave/Minimagick - Cropping is always inaccurate, except when 'y' parameter is 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, jcrop, minimagick

Having implemented the ability to crop as shown in the [Railscasts episode 182 (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised?view=asciicast), I can't seem to  get cropping work accurately. What is cropped is always the top 20% of the area selected in the crop. Except when the 'y' parameter is 0, that is when the cropping area is touching the top of the image. Then cropping works fine.

My implementation is the same as shown in the screencast, except that I am calling the `crop_avatar` method from the controller like this:

```
@profile.crop_x = params[:profile][:crop_x]
@profile.crop_y = params[:profile][:crop_y]
@profile.crop_h = params[:profile][:crop_y]
@profile.crop_w = params[:profile][:crop_w]

@profile.crop_avatar
@profile.save!
```

Also the `crop` method in `avatar_uploader` is implemented like this:

```
def crop
  if model.crop_x.present?
    resize_to_limit(500, 500)
    manipulate! do |img|
      x = model.crop_x
      y = model.crop_y
      w = model.crop_w
      h = model.crop_h
      img.crop "#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}"
      img
    end
  end
end
```

I am using Rails 3.2.1, Carrierwave 0.7.1, JCrop 0.9.12.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but to avoid any future confusion, please review your params. You're setting `:crop_y` twice.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue and I found that resizing the image inside the manipulate! call rather than using the "resize_to_limit" carrierwave helper method solved the problem for me.

```
    def crop
      if model.crop_x.present?
        manipulate! do |img|
          x = model.crop_x
          y = model.crop_y
          w = model.crop_w
          h = model.crop_h
          img.resize "500x500"
          img.crop "#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}"
          img
        end
      end
    end
```

I also highly recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418973/undefined-method-crop-using-carrierwave-with-minimagick-on-rails-3-1-3/9961434#9961434) for more details on what is actually going on in this code.

Comment: My problem is also same. I am using rmagick. And the above solution is not working for me.